# Does prokaryotic transcription have activators / enhancer regions involved?

Tags: microbiology, transcription, transformation

I am designing a biosensor, and I need to know whether prokaryotic transcription involves or can involve (if a gene needs to be regulated) enhancer regions. Also, where are enhancer regions located (how far away from the promotor), and when isolating a promotor region, how do you make sure you are also isolating these enhancer regions?

Comment: This question is too broad. Prokaryotic also have enhancers and repressors, of different kinds, their distance from the promoter may vary a lot. If you can list a particular gene you are interested in then I can have a look. In general, however, the right choice of promoter is often enough for a biosensor.

Comment: I am deriving the promotor from a silver resistance mechanism found on plasmid pMG101. The SilE is transcriptionally controlled by enhancers known as silS and silR (they are sensor / enhancer responder units). What I need is this promotor with neighbouring enhancer regions. I am not sure how to do this....

Comment: Good, you should edit your question then.

Comment: You can find the sequence of the plasmid, with all the detailed coding regions, here: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AF067954 . Once you have the sequence you should design a pair of PCR primers to take out what you need.

Comment: Dang it, primer design. Thanks for your help!